# Retrieve custom document information panel properties using c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, word

I have created a SharePoint library with some custom columns (Request, Response etc..), I go to library settings -> Advanced settings-> Clicked on Edit template link -> saved the word template with .docx. Then I can see all the custom columns in document information panel.

Looks like the following word document.

[image]

When I go to File-> Properties-.Advanced Properties -> I can only see these three properties.

[image]

```
    public static string WDGetCustomProperty(
  string fileName, string propertyName)
    {
        string returnValue = null;

        using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
        {
            var customProps = document.CustomFilePropertiesPart;
            if (customProps != null)
            {
                // No custom properties? Nothing to return, in that case.
                var props = customProps.Properties;
                if (props != null)
                {


                    var prop = props.
                      Where(p => ((CustomDocumentProperty)p).
                        Name.Value == propertyName).FirstOrDefault();
                    // Does the property exist? If so, get the return value.
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        returnValue = prop.InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

By using the above code I can only retrieve these 3 properties (Mentioned in above image). I can retrieve built in property values like Author, last modified by but  I was not able to retrieve the custom property values. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Almost a similar case is found in this post. It is to do with Excel. I hope same will work with Word as well. [accessing-excel-custom-document-properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137763/accessing-excel-custom-document-properties-programatically/1137880#1137880)